# FlatList in react-native and react-native-gesture-handler, what difference?

Tags: react-native

What difference between:

```
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
```

and

```
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
```

Answer (score 16):

[react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler) is more performant with gestures in comparison to react-native's, as they run on the native thread instead of the JS thread.

With react-native's gesture handler, JS handles the event and sends it through the bridge. react-native-gesture-handler will have the native thread directly handle the event.